# Propriedades LinkLabel WindownsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

É possível utilizar a propriedade `LinkLabel` para abrir um tipo de *Modal* para exibir histórico de um determinado item que estão armazenados em tabela ?

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nesse `Form` iria trazes essa inforamção que é abastecidao da tabela `VincoRetornoSefaz`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clicar na Palavra **Rejeitado** ao invés de abrir um link padrão, abrir um novo `form` com o motivo da rejeição.

Comment: é possivel sim, falta o contexto do que fazer exatamente, mas, se poderia colocar um exemplo minimo na sua pergunta para ter uma resposta direcionado a sua dúvida.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editada.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve programar o evento click da label. Ao adicioná-la, dê um duplo click nela que o visual studio já cria e registra o evento. Daí é so criar o formulário, intânciá-lo e usar.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
            {
                Form2 newform = new Form2();
                newform.ShowDialog();
            }
```